# Python vowel filter, appending to string

Tags: python, list, function, lambda

I've had a look around and seen a million and one questions like this, but none quite how I am trying to do this, so please be gentle!

Basically I'm trying to add the vowels in a sentence to a *list???* and print the list, all this by using a lambda called isVowel, and a function called vowelFilter.

I am really unsure how to do this using a lambda, and what I have done so far doesn't seem to work, here's my code;

```
sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the bridge"
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
finalVowel = []
def vowelFilter(sentence):
        for letter in sentence:
                if letter in vowels:
                        finalVowel.append(letter)
        return finalVowel
```

Can you guys shed any light on this? Again I'm well aware this has been asked 1000000000x times but nothing that is 100% like mine, so please be kind!

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want / need to use `lambda`? Sounds like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Works well on my PC. What is the matter?

Comment: Hi Lukas, I've been specifically asked to use a lambda :) and Sheng really?! not working at all for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a lambda expression here is not very pythonic, but if you must:

```
sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the bridge"
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
finalVowel = []

# Return True if arg is in vowels; otherwise, return False
isVowel = lambda arg: arg in vowels

def vowelFilter(sentence):
    for letter in sentence:
        if isVowel(letter):  # Call the lambda to test if letter is a vowel
            finalVowel.append(letter)
    return finalVowel

print (vowelFilter(sentence))
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

> `lambda_expr     ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list]: expression`
>
> `old_lambda_expr ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list]: old_expression`
>
> Lambda expressions (sometimes called lambda forms) have the same
>   syntactic position as expressions. They are a shorthand to create
>   anonymous functions; the expression lambda arguments: expression
>   yields a function object. The unnamed object behaves like a function
>   object defined with
>
> `def name(arguments):
>      return expression`
>
> See section Function definitions for the syntax of parameter lists.
>   Note that functions created with lambda expressions cannot contain
>   statements.

Comment: Hi iCodez, thanks for the reply. I don't know now if this is my laptop but I have used the lambda exactly how you have displayed and still nothing is being printed? Am I missing something?

Comment: @RyanJones - See my edit.  I think you forgot to call the function at the end of the script.

Comment: Why a lambda if you can use a function?

Comment: @CoDEmanX - It is most likely for a school assignment teaching about lambdas.

Comment: Specifically - it's a past paper question for revision :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with a condition. There is no need for a lambda:

```
>>> l = [v for v in sentence if v in vowels]
>>> print l
['e', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
finalVowel = [x for x in sentence if x in vowels]
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

If it's a must to use lambda then you can do it like this (Which is not different than the other two answers)

```
vowel_filter = lambda sent: [x for x in sent if x in vowels]
vowel_filter(sentence)
>>> ['e', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'e']

finalVowel = vowel_filter(sentence)
print finalVowel
>>> ['e', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'e']
```